# Mock Flowable wrapped http response with Mockito

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito, rx-java

I am using Rxjava2's Flowable in my API service using a response wrapper like this :

```
@GET("api/v1/articles") 
Flowable<AResponse<List<Article>>> getArticles(@Query("cat") int cat);
```

I want to test the article presenter by mocking the api request using Mockito,

```
List<Article> mList = new ArrayList<>();
mList.add(new Article());
mList.add(new Article());
doReturn(Flowable.fromArray(mList)).when(mApiService).getArticles(cat);
```

The test failed caused by this exception :

```
"java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com...http.AResponse"
```

How Can I solve this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the `AResponse` object?

You're trying to mock `Flowable` of `AResponse<List<Article>>` (of you're service API interface method `getArticles()`) with `Flowable` of `List<Article>` (`Flowable.fromArray(mList)`), it will not compile as it's not the same object.

You need to create an Object of `AResponse` (which is apparently your custom object) type that will wrap the given `mList`, and then create from it the mocked `Flowable` result.